# The Reference Person class is confusing me

Tags: .net, architecture, domain-driven-design

I am currently reading [Applying Domain-Driven Design with Examples in C# and .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321268202). I have two questions regarding the initial sketch up of the domain model:

1. I am not a native English speaker, so what does a "Reference Person" mean exactly in the business domain or in English in general ?
2. The author commented on the sketch up that the although the "Reference Person" class appears in two different aggregates on the diagram, at run time they are the same instance, how is that possible ? if an aggregate root was garbage collected wouldn't that lead to collecting that instance and thus making the other aggregate unstable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I post the picture we are talking about:

[image]

1. A customer sometime is an organization, not an individual, it may have a list of ReferencePersons that you can contact. We can say that a reference person is the one who represent for an organization. (Aggregate 1)

   When a customer want to place an order, we also need to know exactly the person we are talking to. (Aggregate 2)
2. You should read carefully, the author commented in the book that "The class ReferencePerson is in two different Aggregates in Figure 4-13, but the instances aren't". It means when you load an order and a customer at a same time from database, the Order.ReferencePerson and Customer.ReferencePersons[index] do not point to the same object in memory even they are the same person.

Further more, even they point to the same instance, in .Net objects will be collected when there is no reference to them. If the aggregate 1 was collected but the aggregate 2 still have a reference to the ReferencePerson A, A still is not collected yet.

Comment: +1 for posting the picture (i really should have done that). about the second answer, could you please provide further explanation, and what you can say about deleting a Customer for example, wouldn't that cause all the Reference Persons to go away and now Order will point to a Null reference ?

Comment: That is what confuses me because i prefer to think of the them as a single instance shared by two aggregate because otherwise how are we going to handle conflicts (a reference person was changed in one aggregate but not in the other even though they are the same person) ?